# Postgresql 8.4 for newbies

Tags: database, postgresql

Are there any how-to's or tutorials about postgresql 8.4 fro doing following things:

- Logging in to postgresql
- creating database
- getting into database environment
- adding or altering the tables

Sorry for asking this question here. I googled for 3 hrs online without being able to clarify any of my issues. I also tries the Ubuntu community wiki, it wasn't that much helpful about using a already created database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in your position too, and I agree, it's hard to find anything at a basic enough level. Postgresql is a bit more complicated than MySQL, but it's not impossible to figure out.

The greatest help I've found was this article on Linode Library:
http://library.linode.com/search?query=postgresql (choose your relevant OS/version)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pgadmin, a gui client for PostgreSQL for all these purpose. It is in the software center.

Hope this will help you:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/index.html

Comment: Here is the pgadmin documentation :
http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.10/using.html

Answer (score 1):

This may help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a very similar spot... I have a little bit of MySQL knowledge, and having a bit of trouble figuring out the equivalents in PostgreSQL.

I don't know if it helps any, but one thing that took me a bit to get my head around (still working on it, really) is the concept of 'roles' in postgres vs. 'users' in mysql.  Ch. 20 in the manual (linked above) talks a bit about roles.

Other than that... I'm listening along with ya.  On my Macbook I installed PostgreSQL 9.0.1 lickety-split using a one-click installer from EnterpriseDB and fired up pgAdmin no problemo.  My first attempt at following the chicken-scratch in the Ubuntu Community Wiki ended in failure, as I think I followed the portion for the wrong version of Ubuntu/Postgres :(

Comment: The PostgreSQL portion of this [page](http://russbrooks.com/2009/5/25/install-ubuntu-9-04-server-edition-rails-php-passenger-postgresql-and-mysql) listed in the Wiki seems to be close enough (10.04/Lucid & 10.10/Maveric haven't yet upgraded past pg 8.4) to get things rolling.